# What are the quicker ways to draw graphs than by drawing separate lines?

Tags: c#, graph, xna, drawing

As of now I'm drawing my debug performance graphs with 1px rectangles stretched to necessary height, but drawing a lot of data this way causes significant performance loss.

Currently the logic is: collect all timings for current frame, place them into the `Queue<float>`s and draw a graph for each queue by drawing 300 stretched 1px sprites. There are 4 graphs, so it's 1200 sprites in debug overlay alone, which is resource consuming.

Is there a better way to draw graphs that at least won't require drawing so many sprites?

Comment: I get the impression that you are creating one sprite per line. You can reuse the same one for your 300 draw calls (and all the frames after the first), tinting and rotating it around. This should keep the graphics card relatively happy, with just one texture to upload. I haven't measured it, but the savings should be noticeable.

Comment: @Elideb, no, I'm not that much of a noob anymore. It's just that 1200 draw calls is a lot.

Comment: Excuse my comment. You never know around here =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Line List

You could use [`VertexPositionColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.vertexpositioncolor.aspx) arrays to store individual graph values, then use [`GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196409.aspx) together with a defined [line list (indices)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx#ID4EBE) to draw them with orthographic projection.

[image]

 <sub>The .gif is resized 50% due to file size.</sub>

I'm drawing these samples (4 graphs with 300 value points/pixels each) at 60fps.

[image]

---

### Triangle Strip

If you need to fill the graphs below the line, you could draw a [triangle strip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx#ID4E2BAC) instead (with points at bottom of the graph).

[image]

---

### Line List Code

Here is the relevant code for the first graph rendered above:

```
Matrix worldMatrix;
Matrix viewMatrix;
Matrix projectionMatrix;
BasicEffect basicEffect;

VertexPositionColor[] pointList;
short[] lineListIndices;

protected override void Initialize()
{
    int n = 300;
    //GeneratePoints generates a random graph, implementation irrelevant
    pointList = new VertexPositionColor[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pointList[i] = new VertexPositionColor() { Position = new Vector3(i, (float)(Math.Sin((i / 15.0)) * height / 2.0 + height / 2.0 + minY), 0), Color = Color.Blue };

    //links the points into a list
    lineListIndices = new short[(n * 2) - 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        lineListIndices[i * 2] = (short)(i);
        lineListIndices[(i * 2) + 1] = (short)(i + 1);
    }

    worldMatrix = Matrix.Identity;
    viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
    projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 1.0f, 1000.0f);

    basicEffect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
    basicEffect.World = worldMatrix;
    basicEffect.View = viewMatrix;
    basicEffect.Projection = projectionMatrix;

    basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true; //important for color

    base.Initialize();
}
```

To draw it:

```
foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();
    GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
        PrimitiveType.LineList,
        pointList,
        0,
        pointList.Length,
        lineListIndices,
        0,
        pointList.Length - 1
    );
}
```

For the triangle strip graph, modify the code to display a [triangle strip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx#ID4E2BAC), and for each point in the graph curve put one on the bottom of the graph.

Comment: This way happens to be about ten times as fast. And it has a nice effect of smooth color change from point to point, so I can mark hot spikes with orange! Now to figure out what half of those objects are.

Comment: How do I offset the whole graph?

Comment: @user1306322 You move the `Effect.World` matrix. `basicEffect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(offset);`