# How to draw graph from a list of points?

Tags: graph, xna

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13902970/1306322) to my recent question, there is some code that draws a graph, but I can't manage to edit it into something that accepts any list of points as a parameter.

I'd like the Drawing method to accept these parameters:

- List of `Vector2`, `Point` or `VertexPositionColor`, I can work with whichever.
- Offset for the whole graph

These optional requirements would be appreciated:

- Color that may override `VertexPositionColor`'s color and apply to all points.
- Size of the graph, so it can be shrunk or expanded, either as `Vector2` as multiplier, or `Point` as target size. Maybe even combine this with offset in `Rectangle`.

And if it's possible, I'd like to have it all in a class, so graphs can be used separately from each other, each with its own `Effect.world` matrix, etc.

---

Here is that code (by [Niko Drašković](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020861/niko-draskovic)):

```
Matrix worldMatrix;
Matrix viewMatrix;
Matrix projectionMatrix;
BasicEffect basicEffect;

VertexPositionColor[] pointList;
short[] lineListIndices;

protected override void Initialize()
{
    int n = 300;
    //GeneratePoints generates a random graph, implementation irrelevant
    pointList = new VertexPositionColor[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pointList[i] = new VertexPositionColor() { Position = new Vector3(i, (float)(Math.Sin((i / 15.0)) * height / 2.0 + height / 2.0 + minY), 0), Color = Color.Blue };

    //links the points into a list
    lineListIndices = new short[(n * 2) - 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        lineListIndices[i * 2] = (short)(i);
        lineListIndices[(i * 2) + 1] = (short)(i + 1);
    }

    worldMatrix = Matrix.Identity;
    viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
    projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 1.0f, 1000.0f);

    basicEffect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
    basicEffect.World = worldMatrix;
    basicEffect.View = viewMatrix;
    basicEffect.Projection = projectionMatrix;

    basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true; //important for color

    base.Initialize();
}
```

And the drawing method:

```
foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();
    GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
        PrimitiveType.LineList,
        pointList,
        0,
        pointList.Length,
        lineListIndices,
        0,
        pointList.Length - 1
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm measuring the time taken to draw one frame, and those can get quite big, and there is no limit to it theoretically. I think I'll have to do resizing on my own later.

Comment: I was going to write a rather lengthy dynamic scaling explanation in my comment, but I dumped that thought, since scaling isn't the main problem here. I'm still after a way to draw different graphs independently from one another.

Comment: You should definitely post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

The `Graph` class that does the requested can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Bc5Lk4ap).
<sub>About 200 lines of code seemed too much to paste here.</sub>

[image]

The `Graph` is drawn by passing a list of floats (optionally with colors) to its `Draw(..)` method.

`Graph` properties are:

- `Vector2 Position` - the **bottom** left corner of the graph
- `Point Size` - the width (`.X`) and height (`.Y`) of the graph. Horizontally, values will be distributed to exactly fit the width. Vertically, all values will be scaled with `Size.Y / MaxValue`.
- `float MaxValue` - the value which will be at the top of the graph. All *off the chart* values (greater than `MaxValue`) will be set to this value.
- `GraphType Type` - with possible values `GraphType.Line` and `GraphType.Fill`, determines if the graph will be drawn line only, or bottom filled.

The graph is drawn with a [line list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx#ID4EBE) / [triangle strip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx#ID4E2BAC).

Comment: I can't make it work how I want. I have a `list<vector2>` which holds a parabolic trajectory of a projectile (about 150 points, most of which are on the screen), and it should stay "fixed" to the throw position (`vector2`), but it draws god knows where instead, despite `VertexPositionColor`s in `pointList` looking fine.

Comment: Fixed to the throw position means that the offset is `Vector.Zero` when the graph is first calculated and saved to `List<Vector2>` to draw, and then the game will change the offset, and the graph should move to stay "fixed" from the perspective of the picture on the screen (game level).

Comment: I really just want to draw points at specified coordinates on screen with a given offset and I'd like it to be straightforward, without flipping the whole graph or limiting its range. I can do interpolation/fitting stuff myself, it's not even the priority.

Comment: @user1306322 Do you mean that you don't need a graph, but just a way to draw a list of points as a curve? I was under the impression that this was intended to draw debug information and such. For drawing curves you need a much simpler thing... Just take the code from `DrawLineList` method (`Graph` class), pass it the `BasicEfect` from the constructor, and a `VertexPositionColor[]` you want to draw. When you create individual vertices, just add a `Vector2` offset to them.

Comment: Actually I thought it would be easy to manipulate that class to use it both for debug (milliseconds spent to draw last frame) and drawing curves, trajectories, paths and such. But it turned to be a hell of a job because of those flips and unusual offsets, so I couldn't handle it. When I made my first graph version that just draws a stretched 1px white texture, it started drawing at bottom right origin point to the left (300 lines) and upwards (n px high). I'd like to have something similar to that.

Comment: Fill the List<float> with 300 zeroes initially. Then, when you add new values just remove the first one as well. Remember that the graph `Position` is its **bottom** left corner, and it will be drawn where you position it, in the size specified. If you want to pass only one, then two, then three... up to 300 values, and have them drawn from the right, the class would have to have a property that specifies the number of values to be drawn - is that what you want? As for curves, paths and such - this isn't the class for that, you should have a different one that does that :)